# To take a place of something

Tags: meaning

What does the phrase **take the place of** mean? I found it in the definition [there](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-up-for).

> make up for something - **to take the place of something** that has been
>   lost or damaged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Take the place of something" means "replace".

Examples:

Laptops are starting to take the place of paper and pens in school.

It would be difficult to find someone to take the place of the manager.

Comment: Not much point in answering a straightforward dictionary lookup question with a straightforward dictionary lookup. It'll be closed soon.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Usually I agree with you on such matters, but, in this case, I don't think "straightforward dictionary lookup" applies. If I was an English learner, I'd probably start by looking up "take" and "place" – and likely be quite vexed by the myriad of possibilities I found there. NOAD lists almost 50 verbal definitions of _take_, along with 15 phrases and 23 phrasal verbs (but not "take the place of"). Meanwhile, _place_ gets more than 20 definitions as a noun.

Comment: @J.R. Well said. I'm currently learning two foreign languages and I understand how difficult idioms can be for learners.

Comment: @J.R.: Hmm. Fair enough, I suppose. Searching for the term online returns some decent results quickly enough, but that's not practical for someone using a particular printed dictionary, I guess.

Comment: @Nathan - In cases where an idiom is comprised of words that each have dozens of meanings, I tend to cut our learners some slack. "Can I find this answer easily?" is a fair question, but sometimes I think a better question is, "Could the learner be confused by this easily?"